# Git push error ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git

I am trying push my commit to git but it is showing me following error.

```
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.16 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: cmd: "/build/apps/scm/git-hooks/pre-receive.workspace"
remote: stdin: "6526934c06f745542a87866b3b9bf344fcd909ea    f3a403d6ddaa826829822ac2c6576b86cfb5a60c refs/heads/master"
remote: ret code: "1"
remote: stdout:
remote: pre-receive.workspace script, version 1.2
remote: ERROR: no remote topic branch head of    f3a403d6ddaa826829822ac2c6576b86cfb5a60c
remote: ERROR: Use git wks start then git wks integrate.
remote: ABORTING: one (or more) changesets found not acceptable
remote: stderr:
remote: 
To git@XXXX:/xxx/workspace.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@XXXX:/xxx/workspace.git'
```

I checked "git log" and my change is at the top. I am not able to figure what is it that I am doing wrong. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: According to the hook, what defines a changeset as "acceptable"?

Comment: Dis you try: `ERROR: Use git wks start then git wks integrate.` as the hook itself suggests?

Comment: Thanks guys ! Actually this was internal issue and that git repo had different acceptance criteria to push. As I am new to GIT, I thought that this is general GIT issue. My bad !